# phpmyadmin sql tab is not working properly

Tags: iis, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I installed phpMyadmin-4.5 & mariadb-10.3.13 on iis.
Everything seems fine but when I log into phpMyadmin and click on SQL tab on right upper pane sql-query box is disappeared.
And sql box related css seems not working correctly.
The pane's width is too large.

[image]
[image]

I googled about the situation like this but couldn't find any clue.

Here's html code of that sql-box element

```
<textarea tabindex="100" name="sql_query" id="sqlquery" cols="40" rows="30" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

Display property is none.
Thats why I think css is malfunctioning.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hm..
No one seems to have problem like this one.
I changed the theme to original but didn't worked.
Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: I found the solution. I figured wrong php handler mapping on iis. *.php is correct while I put *.* on it.

Comment: Thank you.. I faced the same problem but in my case I'm using Nginx as web server, so I fixed it by changing site settings to handle all php extension properly. Thanks for the insight. :)